# How to get onActivityResult from lowest version

Tags: java, android

In my app, i have the option to choose picture from gallery. I want to place image on Image view...my code perfectly work(place image on image view) for highest version(API 21) but not working(place image on image view) for lowest version (Api 15). Please any one help me!!

My app config:

```
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

My code here:

```js
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    //private static Bitmap Image = null;

    private ImageView imageView;
    private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;
    private String selectedImagePath = null;
    private Uri mSelectedImageUri;


    Button browseProfilePic;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);//For option menu

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_profilepic, container,
                false);

        imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
       
        browseProfilePic = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_pick);

        browseProfilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                // Show only images, no videos or anything else
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
               startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PHOTO);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == MenuActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO) {
                mSelectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(mSelectedImageUri);
               System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                imageView.setImageURI(mSelectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }
    public String getPath(Uri uri)
    {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) return null;
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String s=cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return s;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // Save the image bitmap into outState
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        outState.putParcelable("bitmap", bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Read the bitmap from the savedInstanceState and set it to the ImageView
        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater ) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_profile_pic, menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_done:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }



    }
```

MenuActivity.java:

```js
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        ProfileFragment pm = new ProfileFragment();
        pm.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        
    }
```

How to fix that..

Thanks for advance.

Comment: can You please explain what exactly is not working?

Comment: Image not set in Image view

Answer (score 0):

- I think your code shouldn't work on any API version. 
  You're creating some Fragment class instance but it is local - it lives only in the `onActivityResult()` scope. 
  The ProfileFragment is already attached to your `MenuActivity` instance, so you should get referece to it's instance using `FragmentManager` or `SupportFragmentManager`'s methods. Creating new `ProfileFragment` object doesn't make sense.
- Another thing is you should call `startActivityForResult` using holder Activity instance context, this way: `getActivity().startActivityForResult(...)`
- in `MenuActivity`'s `onActivityResult()` method put only call to `super.onActivityResult(...)`, nothing more.